# How to use this to target a item in a mapped list in react

Tags: reactjs

I am still pretty new and am doing a simple food ordering app in React. I have a file of dummy meals and am able to create a cart through user input, create a modal on the "Your Cart" button from the header, and map through the cart displaying as a list, but I am unable to figure out how to delete an item from the cart. I realize I need to target the id of the list item that the X is connected to, but for some reason I can't get the this command to work.

Is there something about the this command that I am not understanding when it comes to a mapped list item? So far I have both tried this through my CartModal component and the Home component, but both turn up undefined when using this and I throw an error when using e.target (enter different options like e.target.value, e.target.id, etc...), and have even tried working on an inline targeting (which is where the code below is at currently) but still comes up nothing.

I will add a couple dummy meals to this as well.

Thanks so much!

```
const initialState = 0;
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case "increment":
      return state + 1;
    case "decrement":
      return state - 1;
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const CountContext = React.createContext();

const Home = (props) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    const [count, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const {isVisible, toggleModal} = useModal();

    let totalPrice;

    let cartCounter ;

    const cartUpdaterHandler = (cartItem) =>{
        setCart([...cart, cartItem]);
        cartItem= cartItem;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        cartCounter = cart.length;
        totalPrice = cart.reduce((acc, {price}) => parseFloat(acc) + parseFloat(price), 0).toFixed(2);
    }, [cart])

    const modalHandler = () => {
      toggleModal(true)
    }

    const removeCI = () => {
      console.log(cart)
    }
    

    return (
        <CountContext.Provider 
          value={{ countState: count, 
          countDispatch: dispatch, 
          currentCart: cart
          }}
          className={classes.contextProvider}
          >
          {isVisible && (
            <CartModal 
              overlayClassName="custom_overlay"   
              isVisible={isVisible} 
              hideModal={toggleModal} 
              currentCart={cart} 
              totalPrice={totalPrice}
              remove={removeCI}
              />
          )}
            <Header cart={cart} cartCounter={cart} modal={modalHandler}/>

            <Intro />
            <MealForm onAdd={cartUpdaterHandler} />
            {/* <Cart /> */}
            {/* <CartModal isVisible={isVisible} hideModal={toggleModal} currentCart={cart} totalPrice={totalPrice}/> */}
        </CountContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default Home;


const CartModal = ({ isVisible, hideModal, currentCart, remove}) => {

  // const checkKey = () => {
  //   console.log(cartItem.id)
  //   console.log(this.id)
  // }
  
  
  return isVisible
  ? createPortal(
      <Card className={classes.modal}>
      <div className={classes.modalBackground}>
        <div className={classes.modalDiv}>
          <div className={classes.modalHeader}>
            <h5 className={classes.modalHeaderH5}>Your Cart</h5>
            <button className={classes.modalHeaderX} onClick={hideModal}> X </button>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.modalBody}>          
              {currentCart.map((cartItem, i) => {
                return<div key={Math.random()}>
                  <ul className={classes.cartModalItem} key={Math.random()}>
                    <div className={classes.cartModalItemInfo} >

                      <li className={classes.cartModalName}>{cartItem.name}</li>
                      <li className={classes.cartModalPrice}>{cartItem.price}</li>
                      <li className={classes.cartModalDesc}>{cartItem.description}</li>
                      
                    </div>
//I am asking about the X below this. 
                    <button className={classes.cartModalX} onClick={()=>{console.log(this)}}>X</button>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              })}
              <h5 className={classes.modalTotal}>Total:{currentCart.reduce((acc, {price}) => parseFloat(acc) + parseFloat(price), 0).toFixed(2)} </h5>
          </div>
            <div className={classes.modalFooter}>
                <button className={classes.closeModalButton} onClick={hideModal}> Close </button>
                <button className={classes.orderModalButton}>Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Card>,
      document.body,
    )
  : null;

};


  export default CartModal;

const AvalibleMeals = [
    {
      id: 'm1',
      name: 'Sushi',
      description: 'Finest fish and veggies',
      price: 22.99,
    },
    {
      id: 'm2',
      name: 'Schnitzel',
      description: 'A german specialty!',
      price: 16.5,
    },
    {
      id: 'm3',
      name: 'Barbecue Burger',
      description: 'American, raw, meaty',
      price: 12.99,
    },
    {
      id: 'm4',
      name: 'Green Bowl',
      description: 'Healthy...and green...',
      price: 18.99,
    },
  ];


  export default AvalibleMeals;
```

Comment: Why do you need `this`? Just use `cartItem`.

Comment: @kellys do you know why it points tot the cartItem correctly when I do an inline console.log as opposed to pointing to a function that console.logs the same thing which comes up undefined? Right now I am able to have this work                                                                  <button className={classes.cartModalX} onClick={() => {
                      cartItemToRemove= cartItem;
                      removeItemFromCartHandler(cartItemToRemove)
                      }}>X</button>                                                 but I am sure this can't be the best way to do it